# How to avoid "The data processing extension used for this report is not available. It has either been uninstalled, or it is not configured correctly"

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, odbc

I am using 'MYSQL' datasource  in  ODBC' for my project.

My deployment is failing with the error "Error
 1
An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ODBC' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.
0
0
 "

When I went to the my manager url "http://localhost/Demo_Reports/Pages/DataSource.aspx", I found the following in the 'properties' 'under the 'Data Source Type'

"The data processing extension used for this report is not available. It has either been uninstalled, or it is not configured correctly"

What are the steps to follow to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155086.aspx

Basically, you need to ensure that the DataExtension is installed and also configures in the ReportServer.config file